# JBoss and Apache Load Balancing

Tags: apache, jboss, load, load-balancing, jboss5.x

I am trying to set up a JBoss Cluster with Apache Load Balancing. Basically I have followed the guide from [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingModjk12WithJBoss;jsessionid=1569CBFB7C3096C59C977CD3F7159A32#comment-4181). No problem faced. The only issue I have would be, how do I access my own application? From the guide, it didnt mention how do I mount my own application.

Here's my environment setup:

- Windows XP
- JBoss AS 5.0
- Apache 2.2.16
- mod_jk 1.2.30

Here's my properties setting:

**httpf.conf**

```
Include conf/mod_jk.conf
```

**mod_jk.conf**

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so   
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties   
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log   
JkLogLevel info   
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"   
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompatUnparsed -ForwardDirectories   
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"   
JkMount /application/* loadbalancer   
JkUnMount /application/images/* loadbalancer   
JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties   
JkShmFile run/jk.shm

<Location /jkstatus>
JkMount status
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

**workers.properties**

```
worker.list=loadbalancer,status
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=10.67.51.129
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
worker.node1.prepost_timeout=10000 #Not required if using ping_mode=A
worker.node1.connect_timeout=10000 #Not required if using ping_mode=A
worker.node1.ping_mode=A #As of mod_jk 1.2.27

worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host= 10.67.51.64
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1
worker.node2.prepost_timeout=10000 #Not required if using ping_mode=A
worker.node2.connect_timeout=10000 #Not required if using ping_mode=A
worker.node2.ping_mode=A #As of mod_jk 1.2.27

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2

worker.status.type=status
```

**uriworkermap.properties**

```
/jmx-console=loadbalancer
/jmx-console/*=loadbalancer

/web-console=loadbalancer
/web-console/*=loadbalancer

/admin-console=loadbalancer
/admin-console/*=loadbalancer

/myapp/*=loadbalancer
!/myapp/images/*=loadbalancer
```

**server.xml** in JBoss

```
<Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="node1">
<!-- A AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
  emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" 
  protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="600000" maxThreads="200"/>
```

This is how I start the JBoss

*Comp1*

```
run.bat -c all -g DefaultPartition -u 230.0.0.4 -b 10.67.51.129 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default
```

*Comp2*

```
run.bat -c all -g DefaultPartition -u 230.0.0.4 -b 10.67.51.64 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

My application name is called JBossDB. When i tired to access 10.67.51.129:8080/JBossDB
I am able to launch my application. But if I tried to launch localhost/JBossDB it doesnt load. Note, I am able to launch localhost/admin-console.

I hope I have provided all the necessary info. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add proper address mapping to `uriworkermap.properties` file or to `JkMount` options.

In `uriworkermap.properties` you should put such line:

```
/JBossDB=loadbalancer
/JBossDB/*=loadbalancer
```

OR in `mod_jk.conf` such line:

```
JkMount /JBossDB loadbalancer
JkMount /JBossDB/* loadbalancer
```